# Network Traffic in Javascript

Tags: javascript, web-traffic, network-traffic

I want to know if is there  a way to get the network traffic of a webpage or interface connection using javascript? Basically is to implement tcpdump or Wireshark with javascript.

Any idea?

**Edit**

I want to get all the images/css/etc that a webpage get when it loads and would like to get this information to build a google chrome extension.

Comment: Running JS on the browser or on the server?

Comment: Client. I already my question to be more specific.

Comment: Chrome already does this type of thing with the [network tab](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/network.html) in the console.

Comment: That's exactly what i want to see. How can i do this?

Comment: @GabrielMuñumel just hit f12 in various browsers or look for "Developer Tools" / similar.

Answer (score 0):

So, to get analyze the traffic of your assets you need to be familiar with chrome devTools
Open the devTools by pressing **ctrl+shift+i** (windows) and navigate to [Network panel](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/) and there you can watch the size, time and traffice as well.

Answer (score 0):

May be the global navigator objects property would throw some light.

navigator.network is the property.